# How to uninstall containers from Azure VM [smalldisk] Windows Server 1809 Datacenter with Containers

Tags: azure, containers, windows-server

Usually `Windows Server Core` will use `~6GB` of OS Disk where as Azure VM `[smalldisk] Windows Server 1809 Datacenter with Containers` image took `~16GB` OS disk space.

I would like to bring it back to core size i.e `~6GB`, as I do not use any containers.

As of this posting, Azure does not have any other `smalldisk` images. However I could use image Windows Server 2019 Core (uses `~6GB`) but OS Disk takes `126GB` which is no use in my case.

The only way to reduce my cost is to use available `smalldisk` and uninstall that extra containers.

What are the features that I should turn-off/uninstall?

I tried below but it could frees only `~200MB` space.

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V

Uninstall-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerProvider // not found
```

Comment: This should be on ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

thats just not true, you can use these images:

```
2008-R2-SP1-smalldisk
2012-Datacenter-smalldisk
2012-datacenter-smalldisk-g2
2012-R2-Datacenter-smalldisk
2012-r2-datacenter-smalldisk-g2
2016-Datacenter-Server-Core-smalldisk
2016-datacenter-server-core-smalldisk-g2
2016-Datacenter-smalldisk
2016-datacenter-smalldisk-g2
2019-Datacenter-Core-smalldisk
2019-datacenter-core-smalldisk-g2
2019-Datacenter-smalldisk
2019-datacenter-smalldisk-g2
```

Comment: It's not available for me, and even had a chat with azure team. They confirmed it is not available now.

Comment: well, support folks are often not really knowledgeable about the platform, so they can be wrong, just try and create a vm using the template, just add `2019-Datacenter-smalldisk` to [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-vm-simple-windows/azuredeploy.json#L33) template and try to deploy it.

Comment: `2019-Datacenter-smalldisk` not allowing. Only `2019-Datacenter` that uses `127GB`

Comment: i just deployed it with that smalldisk image, no issues